# Two-dimensional array parameter in Spring Data nativeQuery

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to write a repository method with a native query that uses an SQL function (PostgreSQL) that requires a two-dimensional `text` array as a parameter.

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT * FROM foo_table foo WHERE foo_is_special(foo.bar, :twoDimensionalArray)",
    nativeQuery = true
)
Foo findWhereFooIsSpecial(List<List<String>> twoDimensionalArray);
```

The example above doesn't work, because Spring Data apparently doesn't know how to convert the `List<List<String>>` to a postgresql `text[][]` (it's converted to a `bytea` with a Java-ish string representation of the list).

How can I specify how the parameter should be converted (or in another nice way acheive my goal)?

Comment: can you try `String[][]` instead of `List<List<String>>`

Comment: @YCF_L Yeah, even worse, gets serialized as a `byeta` containing something like `java.lang.String[]@12ea7cd`.